# Base64 Profile Picture returns blank image

Tags: rest-api, c#

I am building an API and one resource we need to pull through for our portal is the Profile photo from Salesforce. I am not returning an error, but the byte string coming back is not presenting the photo in their profile. It presents an empty picture.

Here is the code I am using.

```
public async Task<string> GetRepPhoto(string photoId)
{
    var auth = new AuthenticationClient();
    var url = Properties.Settings.Default.url1;
    await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(Properties.Settings.Default.consumerKey, Properties.Settings.Default.consumerSecret, Properties.Settings.Default.acctName, Properties.Settings.Default.acctPw + Properties.Settings.Default.token, url);
    var client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);

    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(auth.InstanceUrl + "/services/data/" + auth.ApiVersion + "/connect/user-profiles/" + photoId + "/photo "); 
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization: Bearer " + auth.AccessToken);
    req.Method = "GET";

    WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
    byte[] photo = null;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        resp.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);
        photo = ms.ToArray();
    }

    return Convert.ToBase64String(photo);
}

public async Task<string> GetPhotoUrl(string photoId)
{
    var photoString = await GetRepPhoto(photoId);
    return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + photoString;
}
```

Comment: I once had a similar thing happen. The user had clicked update on their user profile picture, and deselected the Show my photo on publicly accessible pages. Might not be your issue though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however, I tested and that is not the issue.

Comment: Not certain, but in a number of places, I think "photo" should be "image".

Comment: Take a look at the Base64 String to Image code being used in this [dailycoding.com](http://www.dailycoding.com/posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx) example. Not entirely sure if you're properly converting to an 'Image' from the String in your above code.

Comment: This does not seem to be the issue. I am not returning the amount of bytes that would constitute a good photo.

Comment: What is the HTTP Status Code on the response? My guess is that it isn't a 200 and the bytes are actually some sort of error message.

Comment: In my response I am receiving an OK message, but -1 on content length. this to me means nothing is coming back. Am I hitting the correct endpoint?